# Sencha Touch 2.x [WARN][Ext.data.reader.Reader#process] JSON object not found

Tags: php, mysql, json, sencha-touch

i am trying to get data from mysql as json to a nested list in Sencha Touch.
Only Problem is i get this Error and dont know why:

```
[WARN][Ext.data.reader.Reader#process] Unable to parse the JSON returned by the server:
```

Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:   data=[ "name":rezepte{"id":"1","name":null,"alter":"Ab 6.Monat","kategorie":null,"tageszeit":"Mittags","portionen":"1 baby- und 1 Erwachsenenportion","bild":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","vorrat":"2",
"zubereitungszeit":"45","zubereitung0":null,"zubereitung1":null,"zubereitung2":null,"info":null}]

```
[WARN][Ext.data.reader.Reader#process] JSON object not found
```

fields containing utf-8 signs appear as null. DB is utf-8_general so i thought it might be the way the json returned looks. switch around but didnt work.

Please let me know what you need to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid or your server responding with invalid JSON.

It should be like this

```
{
   "name":"rezepte",   
      "id":"1",
      "name":null,
      "alter":"Ab 6.Monat",
      "kategorie":null,
      "tageszeit":"Mittags",
      "portionen":"1 baby- und 1 Erwachsenenportion",
      "bild":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
      "vorrat":"2",
      "zubereitungszeit":"45",
      "zubereitung0":null,
      "zubereitung1":null,
      "zubereitung2":null,
      "info":null
 }
```

Comment: Hey man Thank you it helped me. Why are there different types of json formating?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type/15676686#15676686) link